# Displaying check boxes within a block using a div

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to display checkboxes within a block as follows.

```
<div style="overflow: auto; width: 145px; background-color: #FFF; height: 80px; border: 1px double #336699; padding-left: 2px;">
    <label for="chk1"><input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk_param">xxxx</label><br/>
    <label for="chk2"><input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk_param">aaaa</label><br/>
    <label for="chk3"><input type="checkbox" id="chk3" name="chk_param">aaaa</label><br/>
    <label for="chk4"><input type="checkbox" id="chk4" name="chk_param">aaaa</label><br/>
    <label for="chk5"><input type="checkbox" id="chk5" name="chk_param">aaaa</label><br/>
    <label for="chk6"><input type="checkbox" id="chk6" name="chk_param">aaaa</label><br/>
    <label for="chk7"><input type="checkbox" id="chk7" name="chk_param">aaaa</label><br/>
    <label for="chk8"><input type="checkbox" id="chk8" name="chk_param">aaaa</label><br/>
</div>
```

and it displays what is expected as shown in the following [snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGbZc.png).

[image]

When any one (or more) of the checkbox labels is longer than the width specified, a horizontal scroll bar appears which is expected but it displays *the checkbox label text* below the checkbox as shown in the following [snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DulSl.png).

[image]

In this case, one (or more) of the checkbox labels is very long something like the following.

```
<label for="chk1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk_param">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
</label><br/>
```

What is the solution to this? Every checkbox with its label should be displayed  in a straight line **within the block** irrespective of how long the label text is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS property `white-space: nowrap;` like this [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wZNtm/)

Preview

[image]

HTML

```
<div style="overflow: auto; width: 145px; background-color: #FFF; height: 80px; border: 1px double #336699; padding-left: 2px;">
    <label for="chk1"><input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk_param">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</label><br/>
    <label for="chk2"><input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk_param">aaaa</label><br/>
    <label for="chk3"><input type="checkbox" id="chk3" name="chk_param">aaaa</label><br/>
    <label for="chk4"><input type="checkbox" id="chk4" name="chk_param">aaaa</label><br/>
    <label for="chk5"><input type="checkbox" id="chk5" name="chk_param">aaaa</label><br/>
    <label for="chk6"><input type="checkbox" id="chk6" name="chk_param">aaaa</label><br/>
    <label for="chk7"><input type="checkbox" id="chk7" name="chk_param">aaaa</label><br/>
    <label for="chk8"><input type="checkbox" id="chk8" name="chk_param">aaaa</label><br/>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
label {
   white-space:nowrap;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add these 5 css properties to the label:

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/USdKK/

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @Mr.Alien Only if it's too long. Depends what op wants.