# HTML CheckBox labels within a container are not displayed as expected

Tags: html, css

The following HTML code attempts to display checkboxes inside a `<div></div>` container.

```html
<div style="overflow: auto; width: auto; display:block; max-height:130px; max-width:200px; background-color: #FFF; height: auto; border: 1px double #336699; padding-left: 2px;">
    
    <label for="chk12" style='white-space: nowrap;'>
        <input type='checkbox' id="chk12" name='chk_colours' value="12" class='validate[required] text-input text'>
        <div style='background-color:#FF8C00; width: 180px;' title="darkorange">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    </label>    
        
    <label for="chk11" style='white-space: nowrap;'>
        <input type='checkbox' id="chk11" name='chk_colours' value="11" class='validate[required] text-input text'>
        <div style='background-color:#D9D919; width: 180px;' title="brightgold">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    </label>
    
    <label for="chk10" style='white-space: nowrap;'>
        <input type='checkbox' id="chk10" name='chk_colours' value="10" class='validate[required] text-input text'>
        <div style='background-color:#76EE00; width: 180px;' title="chartreuse2">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    </label>
    
    <label for="chk9" style='white-space: nowrap;'>
        <input type='checkbox' id="chk9" name='chk_colours' value="9" class='validate[required] text-input text'>
        <div style='background-color:#2E0854; width: 180px;' title="indigo">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    </label>
    
    <label for="chk8" style='white-space: nowrap;'>
        <input type='checkbox' id="chk8" name='chk_colours' value="8" class='validate[required] text-input text'>
        <div style='background-color:#292929; width: 180px;' title="gray16">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    </label>                    
</div>
```

What it displays can be visible in the following [snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Wmb.png).

[image]

It is seen that various colour stripes which are displayed using the following `<div>` tag

```
<div style='background-color:#FF8C00; width: 180px;' title="darkorange">&nbsp;&nbsp</div>
```

are displayed below their respective checkboxes which are expected to be displayed in a straight line even though I'm using the `white-space: nowrap;` style attribute.

How to display each stripe along with its respective checkbox in a straight line?

---

It was explained in one of my questions itself but in that question each checkbox had a text label in place of such colour stripes. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12884046/1391249) it is. I tried to do as mentioned in the accepted answer of that question but to no avail in this case.

Comment: I suggest you use external CSS instead of the now used inline css. http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/

Comment: @Koen - Thank you. It's just to show as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used `DIV` to mark up the label. The`DIV` is presented as block element by default. Just set it to `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`. Or use another element– such as `SPAN`.

Comment: Using `div` inside `label` is invalid HTML markup (though allowed by HTML5 drafts),  no matter what you do in CSS. Using `span` is the right thing to do (especially when you really want the element to be inline!).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `<div>`s, they're block-elements and that caused them to be not aligned with the checkboxes. 
Try using `<span>`s instead

**EDIT**

Or add `float:right` to the CSS of the colored `<div>`s

**EDIT 2**

using a little CSS:

```
label div{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

​
Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/koenpunt/Ca22j/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Uaq85/

```html
<div style="overflow: auto; width: auto; display:block; max-height:130px; max-width:200px; background-color: #FFF; height: auto; border: 1px double #336699; padding-left: 2px;">

    <label for="chk12" style='white-space: nowrap;'>
        <input type='checkbox' id="chk12" name='chk_colours' value="12" class='validate[required] text-input text'>
        <div style='background-color:#FF8C00; width: 180px;display:inline-block;' title="darkorange">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    </label>    

    <label for="chk11" style='white-space: nowrap;'>
        <input type='checkbox' id="chk11" name='chk_colours' value="11" class='validate[required] text-input text'>
        <div style='background-color:#D9D919; width: 180px;display:inline-block;' title="brightgold">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    </label>

    <label for="chk10" style='white-space: nowrap;'>
        <input type='checkbox' id="chk10" name='chk_colours' value="10" class='validate[required] text-input text'>
        <div style='background-color:#76EE00; width: 180px;display:inline-block;' title="chartreuse2">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    </label>

    <label for="chk9" style='white-space: nowrap;'>
        <input type='checkbox' id="chk9" name='chk_colours' value="9" class='validate[required] text-input text'>
        <div style='background-color:#2E0854; width: 180px;display:inline-block;' title="indigo">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    </label>

    <label for="chk8" style='white-space: nowrap;'>
        <input type='checkbox' id="chk8" name='chk_colours' value="8" class='validate[required] text-input text'>
        <div style='background-color:#292929; width: 180px;display:inline-block;' title="gray16">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    </label>                    
</div>
```